# How to make C# debugging treeview

Tags: c#

I am trying to make treeview same like if we debug some code line, we got treeview information for such line so I want to make exact same C# debugging treeview.

Please if any one suggest me what datatype suits in C# to make treeview same like debugging treeview in it.

Thanks.

Comment: i struggle to understand what you want...do you want to view some variables that your code is updating?  perhaps you should edit your question with an example of your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: [TreeView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch6etkw4.aspx) (assuming you are using Windows Forms)

Comment: I have checked it but could you please tell me in details about C# debugging treeview.

Answer (score 0):

okz,

First Form:
+First Document
when a  mouse a put on "+" its sub nodes will open in new window. Like:

```
 First Document
     .first Page
      + second Page
      .3rd Page
      +4th Page
```

Second Form:

Now when mouse is on "+" of second page node a new window will be open for its subnodes like:

```
secondPage
  .Element1
  .Element2
```

I want to put my treeview data in above format. If a node having subnodes the subnodes should open in new window and if a subnode having subnode these also open in new widow like wise.

The best example for this is C# debugger windows base . Open C# write code. Then debug the code the output in the treeview form and step by step information is provided to users.
There is problem in uploading a picture otherwise i will upload the picture hope u understand the problem. Please note the size of new window should depends upon number of nodes present and if possible there should be autoscrolling option to see subnodes because window size should be small not so large.

Comment: you should edit your original question, clarification of your question does not belong to answers